# Order of calling constructors

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo.Calc("Foo");
    }   
}

public abstract class Base
{
    protected static Func<string, int> CalcFunction;

    public static void Calc(string str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(CalcFunction(str));
    }
}

public class Foo : Base
{
    static Foo() 
    {
        CalcFunction = s => { return s.Length; };
    }
}
```

When I try to call Foo.Calc("Foo"); I have exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
because static constructor of Foo was not called and CalcFunction is null. I don't want to use Init method for Foo class and call it before calling Calc().

Can I change order of calling constructors?

Comment: Mixing inheritance and static members seems odd. If `Calc` and `CalcFunction` weren't static, then `Foo` would have a regular instance constructor, and `CalcFunction` would be initialised before the call to `Calc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - your code has been compiled into

```
Base.Calc("Foo");
```

... so `Foo` isn't being initialized at all.

This isn't a matter of the *order* of static constructors being run... it's that the static constructor for `Foo` simply isn't being run at all.

Basically, you should change your design. You *could* force the static constructor of `Foo` to be run by creating an instance of `Foo`, but that's pretty nasty... your code won't end up being *clear* that way.

Comment: Could you explain why  Foo.Calc("Foo"); will be compiled into Base.Calc("Foo")?

Comment: @ukraine: Because there's no such member as `Foo.Calc` really. The compiler allows `Base.Calc` to be referenced as `Foo.Calc`, but the member you're really referring to is `Base.Calc`, so that's what the emitted code contains.

Answer (score 2):

C# guarantees that, before any code in `Base` is used, the static constructor for `Base` is run. There's nothing to guarantee that any code in `Foo` will run. (You've written a call to `Foo.Calc`, but this is really a call to `Base.Calc`.)

There's no simple fix: you could introduce an explicit init method, or flatten the class hierarchy, or move `CalcFunction` into `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've misunderstood the use of static and abstract keywords. Having an abstract class with only static members makes almost no sense. Are you sure this isn't closer to what you were trying:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo()
        foo.Calc("Foo");
    }   
}

public abstract class Base
{
    protected Func<string, int> CalcFunction;

    public void Calc(string str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(CalcFunction(str));
    }
}

public class Foo : Base
{
    public Foo() 
    {
        this.CalcFunction = s => { return s.Length; };
    }
}
```

Comment: Even better: make `CalcFunction` private and add a constructor: `protected Base(Func<string, int> calcFunction)`